# tarballing a git branch to a remote server using a sudoer

Tags: linux, ssh, git, sudo

I have this compound command working for the root user and have been jumping through hoops trying to get it to work for a sudoer (rsa keys, echoing the pwd, supressing tty etc) but I can't seem to get past this final hurdle:

```
$ git archive --format=tar master | gzip -9c | ssh -t -t user1@xxx.xx.xx.xx "ec
ho password123 | sudo -S tar --directory=test -xvzf -"
```

outputs

```
tcgetattr: Not a character device
[sudo] password for user1:
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Connection to xxx.xx.xx.xx closed.

gzip: stdout: Invalid argument
```

Any ideas??

thx

Comment: Can you update your sudo configuration to be passwordless?  The fact that both sudo, and tar are trying to get data from stdin is a problem.

Comment: The fact that `gzip` reports an error related to `stdin` makes me wonder what happens if you do just `git archive --format=tar master | gzip -9c > /dev/null`.  If that fails, work on that before you try the fancy remote stuff.

Comment: And why do you believe that you need the `-t –t`?

Comment: OK, the `tcgetattr: Not a character device` message may justify the idea that `-t -t` would be helpful.  But, if you’re still getting that `tcgetattr` warning, that suggests that the `-t -t` isn’t helping.

Answer (score 0):

Zoredache is right: the overloading of stdin is a problem.  It might help if you separated the data streams by changing the quoted remote command (after the `xx`) to something like

```
"exec 4<&0; echo password123 | sudo -S tar --directory=test -xvzf - <&4"
```

This should take the stdin to the remote command –– which is the stdin to the `ssh`; i.e., the output from `gzip` –– and shuffle it over to file descriptor 4. 
Then you `echo` the password and pipe it into `sudo –S`, and then run the `tar` with input from file descriptor 4, which is the saved data stream (the output from `gzip`).

OK, that probably won’t work, because `sudo` and `tar` are too tightly coupled.  So, instead, try

```
"exec 4<&0; echo password123 | sudo -S sh –c \"tar --directory=test -xvzf - <&4\""
```

That should provide the extra layer of separation between `sudo` and `tar` to allow `sudo` to read the password and `tar` to read the output from `gzip`.

---

OK, it comes back to me that the file descriptors numbered 3 and higher in the shell are not really the file descriptors with those numbers; they are just arbitrary identifiers used within the shell.  So they don’t transfer from one shell instance to another. 
So let’s give the crank another turn, and try

```
'myfifo=/tmp/myfifo.$$; mkfifo "$myfifo"; cat > "$myfifo"& sleep 1; echo password123 | sudo -S sh –c "tar --directory=test -xvzf - < \"$myfifo\""; rm "$myfifo"'
```

I put the entire remote command into single quotes so none of the dollar signs would be interpreted locally.  I may have quoted more than I really needed to. 
The `sleep 1` is to decrease the probability of a race condition where the `tar` starts reading from the FIFO before the `cat` starts writing to it.

Comment: wow, thanks! it is definitely getting closer, but there appears to be a problem with the file descriptor... is the format correct? 

`tcgetattr: Not a character device`
`[sudo] password for user1: sh: 4: Bad file descriptor`
`Connection to xxx.xx.xx.xx closed.`
`gzip: stdout: Invalid argument`